# SpellCheck Class In Code Behind

Tags: c#, .net, spell-checking

Is there a way to check spelling in code behind?

I only can find how to use it with UI control

```
<TextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Height="20" Width="100"/>
```

What I want is `boolean CheckSpell(string word)`

I don't even need a suggested spelling.

This would used to determine the percentage of correctly spelled words in a text file.
A text file with a real low number was probably not intended for human consumption.

The app has SQL back end so loading a list of words in the Englich dictionary is an option.

Comment: You can create a TextBox class instance without a UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem you can use the [NHunspell](http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net) library.

Your check method in this case is very simple and looks like this:

```
bool CheckSpell(string word)
{         
    using (Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("en_GB.aff", "en_GB.dic"))
    {
        return hunspell.Spell(word);               
    }
}
```

You can find dictionaries on [this site](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Dictionaries).

Also you can use [`SpellCheck`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.aspx) class:

```
bool CheckSpell(string word)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.Text = word;
    tb.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;

    int index = tb.GetNextSpellingErrorCharacterIndex(0, LogicalDirection.Forward);
    if (index == -1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks  Do you have a recommendation?   Speed is factor as I will spell check over 1 million words.

Comment: You're welcome. You must check it. I didn't make performance test.

Comment: OK.  If I get OK performance with SpellCheck I will just hold with that as it is a one time batch.