# Check strings for any spell mistakes

Tags: c#, wpf, string, mapping, match

I have a situation where I am getting the data(names of geographic regions) in string format.(Example:- Asia, Australia) Sometimes I also get strings having more than 1 region(Example:- Europe & Africa, North America and Germany etc). It also happens that the separators for these regions differ but the regions remain the same(Example:- Asia & Africa, Asia-Africa, Asia/Africa etc). The main problem is that this data may be inconsistent. It mas spelling mistakes too.(Example:- Pacific/Pasific etc)

Now all these regions I need to map into a set of buckets, but I have had to do this manually so far. Is there a way where I can automate the mapping of these strings at least to some extent? I have tried to use the soundex function but I decided against it as USA or U.S.A or United States was shown different and Austria and Australia was shown the same.

Thanks for any help

Comment: How do you get these names? Is this a problem of user input or are you receiving these strings from some source on which you have no control?

Comment: It is *not* the responsibility of a developer to correct poorly entered data, but it *is* the responsibility of a developer to have an attempt at their own requirements *before* asking a question on Stack Overflow. Please show us what YOU have tried so far.

Comment: @Steve We use Bloomberg data. So we have no control over it. We have asked Bloomberg if they themselves have a way n they said that they provide the data the way it was provided to them.

Comment: @Sheridan Like i said. I have tried using the soundex method and also the string difference method. but chose not to use it as they are not fool proof..

Comment: Well, this is a difficult scenario then. The only thing that I can think now is some kind of learning tool. Suppose two tables, one with normalized regions and another with these variables strings linked together with a common code. Search in the variable table and look if you have a normalized version, otherwise add the new string and ask to manually reconcile it. Over the time the manual workload should decrease. (If the number of variations is not infinite)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a (fuzzy) search engine ? (e.g. Lucene).

For this, I would do the following:

1. Create 1 document per region, containing all synonyms that are valid for said region. (Make sure that each synonym is unique in the whole index)
2. Tokenize the synonyms based on the set of rules you have for multi-region strings (something that splits on punctuation should be a good start)
3. Search each input over the index by using the same tokenization rules.

At the end, you get a score of top matches.

You can handle spelling mistakes with FuzzyQuery (e.g. if errors are permitted in the input), giving an Edit Distance as the parameter.

Keep in mind that no matter what you do, if you cannot control the quality of the input, you will get some (read: can be a lot) false positives.

Comment: Thanks a ton man.. Ill check this out. Also i know 100% mapping is not posslible, but if it can reduce my manual work by even 50% its great.. cheers. :D

Comment: can you give a quick thought on what you mean by synonyms??

Comment: You gave them yourself, e.g. "USA",  "United States of America", can be considered as synonyms, and thus would be considered to be the same document/physical region.

Answer (score 0):

I would spell check
[spell check in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541038/spellcheck-class-in-code-behind)
From there create synonyms
Count the misspelled words
Start with synonyms for the most common misspelled

You could also use levenshtein distance to find similar words

Even with English I would not recommend soundex.